# Parsing of collection validator failed :: caused by :: Unknown $jsonSchema keyword: examples in MongoDB/Ajv/Typebox

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, fastify, ajv

I'm using an **Atlas** based mongodb instance and fastify for backend. I'm also using @sinclair/**typebox** to generate JSON Schemas for data validation. Normally, I use these schemas to **validate input messages** but I now want to **reuse them as validators for MongoDB** collections too.

I have something like this:

```js
    await database.command({
      collMod: 'users',
      validator: {
        $jsonSchema: UserSchema,
      },
    });
```

And also, I have examples set for some of the fields. e.g.:

```js
export const HandleSchema = Type.RegEx(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,24}$/, {
  examples: ['harry-potter', 'jane-doe-99'],
  title: 'Handle',
  // ...
});

export const UserSchema = Type.Object(
  {
    _id: HandleSchema,
    // ...
  },
  { additionalProperties: false },
);
```

However, I'm getting this error while trying to apply this validator:

> Parsing of collection validator failed :: caused by :: Unknown $jsonSchema keyword: examples

Which means the `examples` keyword is not recognized by MongoDB; and unfortunately looks like this happens in server side. Looks like they [dared to ignore](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30723) the behavior suggested by the spec. I'm also seeing a flag that can be used to [ignore unknown keywords](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/ce71ccd92747972654c92fe9438df9c633188f93#diff-5732722664308f17bd3b2815eb7a3929edd874d33b3cbdeddf6ab7a7216a306a), but unfortunately, `setParameter` [doesn't work with atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/unsupported-commands/#unsupported-commands-1).

Now, at least I should be able to remove `examples` somehow from typebox or ajv. I tried `Type.Strict(UserSchema)` and `ajv.customOptions.keywords` set to `['examples']` (this probably is the inverse of what I want to achieve), but they didn't work.

How do I ignore `examples` field just for the mongodb schema? Or how do I fix this from MongoDB Atlas side (looks impossible)? Any other approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of how much I dislike this approach, I went for a "temporary" solution.

Since the end result of a json schema -- as mongodb sees it -- is nothing more than a plain old javascript object. So I wrote a utility function to recursively strip-out the unnecessary fields.

```js
import { TObject, TProperties } from '@sinclair/typebox';

export function stripExtras<T extends TProperties>(
  obj: TObject<T>,
  exclude: string[],
): TObject<T> {
  const result: { [k: string | symbol]: any } = {};

  for (const key in obj) {
    if (exclude.includes(key)) {
      continue;
    }

    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      result[key] = stripExtras(obj[key], exclude);
      continue;
    }

    if (
      Array.isArray(obj[key]) &&
      obj[key].length > 0 &&
      typeof obj[key][0] === 'object'
    ) {
      result[key] = obj[key].map((item: TObject<TProperties>) =>
        stripExtras(item, exclude),
      );
      continue;
    }

    result[key] = obj[key];
  }

  return result as Exclude<TObject<T>, typeof exclude[number]>;
}
```

This is not completely accurate, especially the type definitions; I'll keep improving it. However, it does what I want.

```js
const UserSchemaStripped = stripExtras(UserSchema, [
  'examples',
  'const',
  'default',
]);
```

Looks like `examples` was not the only field that mongodb reject.

And I'm using the stripped version only for the MondoDB.

```
   await database.command({
      collMod: 'users',
      validator: {
        $jsonSchema: UserSchemaStripped,
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of doing something very similar to what you are doing. Have you tried using an `Unsafe` type. [As described in the documents](https://github.com/sinclairzx81/typebox#unsafe-types):

> Use `Type.Unsafe(...)` to create custom schemas with user defined inference rules.

So in your case you could so something like this:

```
import { Type } from '@sinclair/typebox';
import type { Static, TSchema } from '@sinclair/typebox';

function RegExType<T extends TSchema>(schema: T) {
    const { examples, ...rest } = schema;
    return Type.Unsafe<Static<T>>({ ...rest });
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
const HandleSchema = RegExType(
    Type.RegEx(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,24}$/, {
        examples: ['harry-potter', 'jane-doe-99'],
        title: 'Handle',
        // ...
    })
);

export const UserSchema = Type.Object(
    {
        _id: HandleSchema,
    },
    { additionalProperties: false },
);

/** UserSchema object looks like this:
{
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "title": "Handle",
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,24}$"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "id"
    ]
}
*/
```

Now I am not 100% certain this is the correct way of handling things as I'm still learning the library, but by the looks of it, it seems to do what you described. Unless I misunderstood your question.

You said you wanted to reuse the schema both for ajv and mongodb. I am not sure if you can use the exact same schema object to do both, but what you can easily do is make a wrapper function that outputs 2 schemas, for ajv and mongodb, depending on some parameter you pass to it.

Personally I think that would be a better implementation than writing a recursive function that strips out unnecessary keys.

Comment: So this means if I want to remove many fields (`['examples', 'const', 'default']`) from many schemas, I should write a function (like the above) that excludes all of those fields and wrap each schema with the function call? Will try this. 

Also, In my recursive version, I'm using the stripped version of schema only for mongodb.

Comment: @Wickramaranga yes, that's what I had in mind. Something like `function generateSchema(isMongoSchema: boolean) { return Type.Object({ ...isMongoSchema ? CustomType() : Types.RegEx() }) }`. Obviously this is just a simplified pseudo-code version. You could also open an issue on github, the library seems very well supported - https://github.com/sinclairzx81/typebox/issues